# Search with count in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php 
    $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","abc","xyz");
?>
```

Hello everyone, i have following array,above is the code,How can i search and get total number of values after "BMW".please help me with the above problem.

To clarify, I want the answer 3 in this case and if the value does not exist I would like the answer 5

Comment: Please don't revert edits that improve the formatting of your posts

Comment: please share what have you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work

```
echo count($cars) - (array_search('BMW', $cars) + 1);
```

This would be a little safer, just in case the value does not exist in the array.

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","abc","xyz");
if ( array_search('BMW', $cars) !== FALSE ) {
    echo count($cars) - (array_search('BMW', $cars)+ 1);
}else{
    echo 'BMW Does not exist in the array';
}
```

If you want the answer 5 if the item does not exist this might be what you want

```
echo count($cars) - (array_search('BMWX', $cars) !== FALSE ?  array_search('BMWX', $cars)+ 1 : 0);
```

Or to simplify

```
echo count($cars) - array_search('BMWX', $cars);
```

will also give the answer 5